# a FIFO query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

I'm building a stock management app in `c#` with `SQL server`. I want to make a `FIFO` query from my table.

I purchased same products in variable rate. After that I sold some of them. I want to query based in "First in first out" according to `BatchDate` column. So I want to get the available in stock products with PurchasePrice.

Here is my table:
`

```
CREATE TABLE InventoryLedgers
(

    BatchNo nvarchar(30),
    BatchDate datetime,
    ProductId int,
    StockIn decimal(18, 2),
    StockOut decimal(18, 2),
    PurchasePrice decimal(18, 2),
    SalesPrice decimal(18, 2)
);


INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000001', '10/20/2017', 1, 2, 0, 35000, 0);

INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000002', '10/21/2017', 1, 3, 0, 36000, 0);

INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000003', '10/22/2017', 1, 5, 0, 37000, 0);

INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000004', '10/20/2017', 2, 3, 0, 40000, 0);

INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000005', '10/21/2017', 2, 3, 0, 42000, 0);

INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000006', '10/22/2017', 2, 5, 0, 46000, 0);


INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000007', '10/22/2017', 1, 0, 3, 0, 45000);

INSERT INTO InventoryLedgers (BatchNo,BatchDate ,ProductId ,StockIn ,StockOut ,PurchasePrice ,SalesPrice)
VALUES ('JRV171000008', '10/22/2017', 2, 0, 4, 0, 50000);
```

[image]

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: First, do not post tables structure, sample data and your code as images, we need them as formatted text, second, what did you try so far? third, be clear and specify your issue.

Comment: I need how many product, and value

Comment: What you need is try to do it yourself first. SO is not a code writing service. Most likely you're need sum() over your dates, with in & out amounts.

Answer (score 4):

using "running sums" created by `sum(...) over(...)` for stockin and stockout allows us to determine when stockin exceeds stockout using FIFO logic.

> ```
> WITH cte AS (
>       SELECT
>             *
>       , sum(stockin)  over(partition by ProductId order by BatchDate ASC) sum_in
>       , sum(stockout) over(partition by ProductId order by BatchDate ASC) sum_out
>       FROM InventoryLedgers
>       )
> SELECT
>       i.id, i.BatchNo, i.BatchDate ,i.ProductId ,i.StockIn
>     , i.PurchasePrice, i.sum_in - o.sum_out as tot_avail_stock
> FROM cte i
> inner join (
>             select *
>             from cte
>             where stockout > 0
>           ) o on i.ProductId = o.ProductId and i.sum_in > o.sum_out
> where i.stockin > 0
> order by productid, batchdate
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | BatchNo      | BatchDate  | ProductId | StockIn | PurchasePrice | tot_avail_stock
> -: | :----------- | :--------- | --------: | :------ | :------------ | :--------------
>  2 | JRV171000002 | 21/10/2017 |         1 | 3.00    | 36000.00      | 2.00           
>  3 | JRV171000003 | 22/10/2017 |         1 | 5.00    | 37000.00      | 7.00           
>  5 | JRV171000005 | 21/10/2017 |         2 | 3.00    | 42000.00      | 2.00           
>  6 | JRV171000006 | 22/10/2017 |         2 | 5.00    | 46000.00      | 7.00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=667b4b8704966a9a1c59c0ead0d2bb11)*

Answer (score 1):

At first I created a PROCEDURE. Later on, the PROCEDURE'S data joining the other side of the procedure with another TABLE.

```
WITH OrderedIn as (
    select ProductId Item, Date = BatchDate , Qty=StockIn, Price = PurchasePrice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY ProductId, [BatchDate]) as rn
    from InventoryLedgers
    where StockIn > 0
),
RunningTotals as (
    select Item, Qty, Price, CAST(Qty AS int) AS  Total, CAST(0 AS int) as PrevTotal, rn from OrderedIn where rn = 1
    union all
    select rt.Item, oi.Qty, oi.Price, CAST(rt.Total AS int)  + CAST(oi.Qty AS int), CAST(rt.Total AS int) Total, oi.rn
    from
        RunningTotals rt
            inner join
        OrderedIn oi
            on
        rt.Item = oi.Item and rt.rn = oi.rn - 1
), TotalOut as (
    select Item=ProductId, SUM(StockOut) as Qty from InventoryLedgers where StockOut>=0 group by ProductId
)
select
    rt.Item, SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(PrevTotal AS int) > out.Qty THEN rt.Qty ELSE CAST(rt.Total AS int) - out.Qty END * Price) price
from
    RunningTotals rt
        inner join
    TotalOut out
        on
            rt.Item = out.Item
where
    CAST(rt.Total AS int) > CAST(out.Qty AS int)
group by rt.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer accumulated tot_available_stock where might not be intuitive for inventory tracking. Also his answer didn't cover never sold the stock situation.
On top of Paul's answer, here is my revised solution.

Below is my test dataset. I added warehouse which fits my case.

```
id| ProductID | StockIn | StockOut | Price |  BatchDate | WH |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
01|         A |       5 |        0 |    20 | 2020-01-01 | AZ |
02|         A |      10 |        0 |    30 | 2020-02-01 | AZ |
03|         A |       0 |       12 |    20 | 2020-02-02 | AZ |
04|         A |       1 |        0 |    30 | 2020-02-03 | AZ |
05|         B |       1 |        0 |   100 | 2020-02-03 | AZ |
06|         A |       1 |        0 |    50 | 2020-02-04 | CA |
```

Below is my solution (MySQL)

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT
            *
      , sum(stockin)  over(partition by ProductId, WH order by BatchDate ASC) sum_in
      , sum(stockout) over(partition by ProductId, WH order by BatchDate ASC) sum_out
      FROM InventoryLedgers
      )
SELECT
      i.id, i.ProductId, i.sum_in - o.sum_out as tot_avail_stock, i.Price, i.BatchDate, i.WH
FROM cte i
left join (
            select ProductID, WH, max(sum_out) as sum_out
            from cte
            where stockout > 0
          ) o on i.ProductId = o.ProductId and i.WH = o.WH and i.sum_in > o.sum_out
WHERE 
      i.stockin > 0
HAVING 
      tot_available_stock is not null
UNION ALL
Select 
      id, ProductID, StockIn as tot_avail_stock, BatchDate, WH
FROM 
      InventoryLedgers
where
      (Target, WH) NOT IN(
      Select 
            ProdctID, WH
      FROM
            InventoryLedgers
      WHERE 
            Sell_Qty>0)
ORDER BY 
      WH, ProductID;
```

Result looks like this

```
id| ProductID | tot_avail_stock | Price |  BatchDate | WH |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
02|         A |               3 |    30 | 2020-02-01 | AZ |
04|         A |               1 |    30 | 2020-02-03 | AZ |
05|         B |               1 |   100 | 2020-02-03 | AZ |
06|         A |               1 |    50 | 2020-02-04 | CA |
```