# Is there a SQL Statement to queries Invoice and receive using FIFO allocation

Tags: t-sql, recursion, join

I have list of invoice and list of receive, would like to allocate the receive using FIFO method.

I have seen several examples like :

[FIFO SQL Query for stock and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253040/fifo-sql-query-for-stock-and-value)

[a FIFO query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114895/a-fifo-query-in-sql-server)

Both solve using CTE, I just don't get the clue, similar but how to do it in my case

Here the examples data:

```
create table #inv (invoice_id nvarchar(10), invoice_amt money)
insert into #inv select 'IV1','500'
insert into #inv select 'IV2','2500'
insert into #inv select 'IV3','3000'

create table #pay (receive_id nvarchar(10), receive_amt money)
insert into #pay select 'PY1',500
insert into #pay select 'PY2',1000
insert into #pay select 'PY3',1000
insert into #pay select 'PY4',1000
```

The result should :

```
   IV1  500     PY1 500
   IV2  2500    PY2 1000
   IV2  2500    PY3 1000
   IV2  2500    PY4 500
   IV3  3000    PY4 500 (some miss type previously should 500 not 50)
```

- IV1 fully paid by PY1
- IV2 is paid by PY2, PY3 and PY4(500)
- IV3 if paid by PY4 (500)

Could do this using traditional LOOP method, but using CTE  or several SQL Queries would better if possible.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Table #pay should probably have a column invoice_id so that they can be matched.  That would highlight any outstanding balances of each invoice.  Also I suspect that there is a column CustomerID in each table ??

Comment: Yes you right, the customer did no type the invoice number  when he/she transfer the money. So we simple allocate it by first in first out

Comment: Tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature. Unless you have a column you can use for `order by`, you can't do FIFO since there is no "first row".

Comment: Invoice_id and receive_id are primarykey in each tables. Sort/Order  and fifo order are based on these two columns

Comment: @zohar if you need, just add new row identity(1,1) act as primarykey in each table or select row_number() over (order by invoice_id) as rowid, * into #newtbl from table_invoice. But now how to generate the result set ? Using cte or over ? Upvote the question for more people to help :)

Comment: @Sen above example uses "full" payments, Please tell us expected results when PY1 is 800.  Should 300 flow down to IV2? etc all the way down the line?  Or when PY1 is 100? etc

Comment: @donPablo, yes you're correct in FIFO method, if PY1 800 then 500 will allocate to IV1 and 300 to IV2. And if PY1 100 then IV1 (PY1 100, PY2 400) then IV2 2500 (PY2 600, PY3 1000, PY4 900)

Comment: @Sen what is the traditional LOOP method? Is the loop executed in sqlserver or outside in the application?  "LOOP" seems to have a negative connotation - why is that?  I would not want to develop a process that is not acceptable.   Is there a CompanyID column in the table(s)?  Need more on the DDL.

Comment: @don using double loop in storage procedure loop invoice & receive. And yes both are same customer oc

Comment: @Sen I think that two cursors (invCursor and payCursor) are the only way to go. While @ invEOF = 0 or @ payEOF = 0.